# Why my onclick doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new on this field, and have tried this for a long time. You can see my simple version here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YeahrG28bT2izX8gMKor?p=preview

Could you tell me why my onclick here doesn't work? My button is the `2signUp` botton, Thanks!

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainControl', function($scope) {
  $scope.logged = false;
  $scope.visiter = true;
  var sub1 = document.getElementsByClassName("haha")[0];
  sub1.onclick=function(){
    $scope.logged = !$scope.logged;
  }
})
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainControl">
        <div ng-show="logged">
            <button>1Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="visiter">
            <button class="haha">2Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="logged">
          hello
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You are using `document.getElementsByClassName("haha")[0]` but `haha` is id. You should use `document.getElementById`

Comment: Why don't you use the ng-click functionality?

Comment: See @Falk, there are exceptions, but generally you should avoid mixing Angular with JQuery.

Comment: Your template won't pick up the changes to $scope variables using a javascript function like that

Comment: yes, i change into class

Comment: don't use `onClick` with angular, you are defeating one of the main features of how angular is designed by doing this.

Comment: Ok, I will go to search and learn it well, thanks!

Comment: @Jaco he is not using jQuery, it's vanila Js ;) but you are right. Do not mix it;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Angular way of handling click events, don't use any `document.getElementById()` jazz when you have angular to do the work for you.

This is why you should let angular handle it

> **Data Binding**
>
> Data-binding is an automatic way of updating the view whenever the model changes, as well as updating the model whenever the view changes. This is awesome because it eliminates DOM manipulation from the list of things you have to worry about.
>
> https://angularjs.org/

Use Angular's [**ngClick**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainControl', function($scope) {
  $scope.logged = false;
  $scope.visiter = true;
  $scope.signup = function() {
    $scope.logged = !$scope.logged;
    alert("ran the function");
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainControl">
  <div ng-show="logged">
    <button>1Sign Up</button>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="visiter">
    <button id="haha" ng-click="signup()">2Sign Up</button>  <!-- use ngClick here! -->
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="logged">
    hello
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```